# Cannot upload to s3 with nodejs generated signed url

Tags: c#, node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have a nodejs application, which is generating a signed url for uploading files to AWS S3. I want to use this signed url to upload a file to S3 from a C# winforms application.

In my C# code, when I use the signed url that I get from my nodejs server for uploading a file to S3, I get this error:

```
The connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

But if I use C# for generating the signed url, the file successfully uploads. I tried encoding and decoding the url that I get from nodejs with no luck. Both C# and nodejs server work in my localhost, so there should be no time difference.

Example url that is generated by c# (working) and by nodejs (not working):

```
// c# generated, works
https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder/547dac915711b69f18241920.flv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAILNOHZMPD62PBJGQ&Expires=1417970769&Signature=8ePjR1%2FrQb35YU2AR%2B6480vjiuM%3D

// nodejs generated, does not work
https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder/547dac915711b69f18241920.flv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAILNOHZMPD62PBJGQ&Expires=1417967527&Signature=rIbJ2zuknWwFG92Lh7VGAhqYE0I%3D
```

The nodejs code generating the signed url:

```
// this signed url does not work
var params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: folder + "/" + filename, Expires: 3600 };
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, callback);
```

The c# code generating the signed url:

```
// this signed url works
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = "mybucket",
    Key = "folder/" + _id + ".flv",
    Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
};

string url = null;
url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

C# code uploading the file:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}

HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Why is my nodejs generated url does not work but my C# generated url works? How can I get my nodejs generated signed url to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this. The problem was on this line in nodejs code:

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, callback);
```

which should be

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, callback);
```

instead.